# Ошибка в простой программе с#

Tags: c#

Реализовываю программу для подсчёта квадратного уравнения. Выбивает такие ошибки:

> k_r.cs(9,13): error CS1002: Требуется ";".
> k_r.cs(9,13): error CS1056: Недопустимый символ "-".

Сам код:

```
using System; // Kvadr. Rivn. XIO
namespace kv_r
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a = 2, b = -5, c = 3, d, x1, x2;
            d = b * b – 4 * a * c;
            if (d < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No real answers!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (d == 0)
                {
                    x1 = -b / (2 * a);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n X1={0} ",x1);
                }
                else
                {
                    x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
                    x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n X1={0} X2= {1}",x1,x2);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n Press <ENTER> ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас в вычислении дискриминанта стоит не минус, а другой символ, который похож на минус.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В выражении `d = b * b – 4 * a * c;` стоит тире вместо минуса.

Должно быть `d = b * b - 4 * a * c;`